# re: substract static value with values of dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, warnings, static-variables

I talked about this issue in another post but I didn't explain myself with clarity, apologizes, I'm new here.
The problem that I have seems a bilge but I do not manage to see what I'm doing wrong.
In first place I have this DatFrame in which there is a series of times in milliseconds, this dataframe can change in length, since the information is dynamic:

```
    ts
1   1393867136438
2   1393867136438
3   1393867136407
4   1393867136438
5   1393867136423
6   1393867136438
7   1393867136438
```

I have the following function in which I want to do this operation:
I want to deduct to  1392217780000, each of the positions of the Dataframe "ts" previous, I will have X results depending on the size of the dataframe and  I want to guard the results in a vector that then I pass to Dataframe.

```
get_ms_ts_list<-function(ts_list){
  ms_ts_list <- vector()
  static_num <- 1392217780000
  for (i in 1:length(ts_list[,1])){
    ms_ts_list[i] <- static_num-ts_list[i,1]
  }  
return(as.data.frame(ms_ts_list))
}
```

When I use this function I obtain these warnings and it generates me the dataframe that I've put here plenty of “Na’s”, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong ? Any idea ? thanks

```
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors
7: In Ops.factor(static_num, ts_list[i, 1]) : - not meaningful for factors



    ms_ts_list
1   NA
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
6   NA
7   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`ts_list` is not a number.  It is a factor.  You can change it to a number by:

```
as.numeric(levels(ts_list))[ts_list]
```

([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)).

Comment: Well, I tried that code and it gives me a syntax error "Error in as.numeric(levels(ts_list))[ts_list] :invalid subscript type 'list'", I've also tried other variations for example: as.numeric(levels(ts_list)) or as.numeric(ts_list);  and only continues the same error: "not meaningful for factors"

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer

```
get_ms_ts_list<-function(ts_list){
  ms_ts_list <- vector()
  static_num <- 1392217780000
  #as.numeric(levels(ts_list))[ts_list]
  for (i in 1:length(ts_list[,1])){
    ms_ts_list[i] <- (static_num)-(as.numeric(as.character(ts_list[i,1])))
  }
  return(as.data.frame(ms_ts_list))
}
```

thanks anyway